# Why am I getting “Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: unsupported pseudo: is” when using “:first:is”

Tags: jquery, forms, css-selectors

I am trying to select an empty form date element (first element) using jQuery 3.7.1 but I am constantly getting errors with this command and using this CSS selector. The error is this:

> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: unsupported pseudo: is

The jQuery command and CSS selector is this:

```
$('#the_form').find("input[type='date'][name='the_date[]']:first:is(input[value=''])");
```

I am testing and developing with Firefox 119.0.1 (64-bit) on macOS Sonoma (14.1.1; 23B81). Why the heck am I getting this “unsupported pseudo: is” error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Use `:first-of-type:is` instead of `:first:is`.

I don’t know why the initial error shows up, but it resolves itself when I using `:first-of-type:is` instead of `:first:is`:

```
$('#the_form').find("input[type='date'][name='the_date[]']:first-of-type:is(input[value=''])");
```

It seems like the issue is with `:is` and with the Sizzle CSS selector engine. The issue is documented [here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/4884) and apparently [will be addressed in jQuery 4.0](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/4884#issuecomment-834418601)? Who knows! For now, `:first-of-type` works with `:is` for my usage.

Hopefully this will help someone else as well!